# PHP setter function

Tags: php, class, set

I have a class like:

```
class MyClass
{
    public static $myVariable;
}
```

... and inside I have this:

```
public static function set($name, $value)
{
    if (true === property_exists('MyClass', $name)) {
        self::$name = $value;
    }
}
```

How can I replace:

```
self::$name
```

... with the real variable name? I have try:

```
self::{$name}
```

... but it works only for methods. I want to have the possibility of change MyClass's variables with a function. For example:

```
MyClass::set('myVariable', 123);
```

Some ideas?

Comment: Does `self::$name` not work?

Comment: No, it search $name as class variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`self::$$name` should do the trick.

Comment: `"As opposed with isset(), property_exists() returns TRUE even if the property has the value NULL."`

Yup, `static::${$name}` looks better.